# How can chrome.tabs.query show information of all tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am new to Chrome extension developing. As far as I know, **chrome.tabs.query** only works in background.js, and I was trying to use the code below to check out the information returned. However, the result only returns to the background page  console, and it only gives me the information of "chrome://extensions/" page.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  console.log("tab ID:");
  console.log(tabs);
});
```

How can I get the information of all/any of the tabs that is opening in the current window?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You just need to remove `active` key from query method, because it returns the current tab you are staying on.
So all the tabs of the current window will be returned by the following:

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        console.log('Tab ID: ', tab.id);
    });
});
```

for more details you could take a look at `query` method docs [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)